# Proper handling of parallel function that writes output in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a text file as input, does some processing, and writes a pickled result to file. I'm trying to perform this in parallel across multiple files. The order in which files are processed doesn't matter, and the processing of each is totally independent. Here's what I have now:

```
import mulitprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

def processor(fi):
    df = pd.read_table(fi)
    ...do some processing to the df....

   filename = fi.split('/')[-1][:-4]
   df.to_pickle('{}.pkl'.format(filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    files = glob('/path/to/my/files/*.txt')
    pool = mp.Pool(8) 

    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(processor, files):
        pass
```

Now, this actually works totally fine as far as I can tell, but the syntax seems really hinky and I'm wondering if there is a better way of going about it. E.g. can I get the same result without having to perform an explicit loop?

I tried `map_async(processor, files)`, but this doesn't generate any output files (but doesn't throw any errors).

Suggestions?

Comment: did you try adding `print` statements to make sure it was actually running when you tried `map_async`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map_async`, but you need to wait for it to finish, since the `async` bit means "don't block after setting off the jobs, but return immediately". If you don't wait, if there's nothing after your code your program will exit and all subprocesses will be killed immediately and before completing - not what you want!

The following example should help:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from time import sleep

def my_func(val):
    print('Executing %s' % val)
    sleep(0.5)
    print('Done %s' % val)

pl = Pool()
async_result = pl.map_async(my_func, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

res = async_result.get()
print('Pool done: %s' % res)
```

The output of which (when I ran it) is:

```
Executing 2
Executing 1
Executing 3
Executing 4
Done 2
Done 1
Executing 5
Done 4
Done 3
Done 5
Pool done: [None, None, None, None, None]
```

Alternatively, using plain `map` would also do the trick, and then you don't have to wait for it since it is not "asynchronous" and synchronously waits for all jobs to be complete:

```
pl = Pool()
res = pl.map(my_func, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print('Pool done: %s' % res)
```

Comment: Great answer with useful examples. But one clarification: do you expect any performance difference between the two approaches you describe? Why or why not?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a difference; I would imagine `map()` just calls `map_async()` and then waits for the result, in the same way my first example does, but I haven't checked the code.

[edit since I hit enter instead of shift-enter, doh]

Anyway, if you are using multiprocessing that should be because you have a lot of work to do in each of the functions you are spinning off, therefore the overhead difference between `map` and `async_map + get` should be negligible. If it isn't, I think you don't need to to be using multiprocessing!

Comment: Great, thanks! And yes the work is certainly non-negligible. I'm just trying to learn best practices.